# why does this return empty space in beginning?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$here = "/1/2/3/4/ ";

$test = explode('/', $here);
var_export($test);
?>
```

Why does output have a 0 => '' .. shouldn't it be 0 => 1

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '2',
  3 => '3',
  4 => '4',
  5 => ' ',
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your string starts with a `/` and `explode()` splits a string up into an array using the delimiter you specify (`/`). Every time explode encounters your delimiter, it will take any characters preceding it since the last delimiter and add it to the array (`explode()` operates left to right).

This happens even if there is nothing preceding the delimiter (e.g. when your string starts with the delimiter or you have two delimiters back to back).

You probably want something like this:

```
$test = explode('/', trim($here, '/'));
```

Which will trim leading or trailing slashes, avoiding empty array items. You may also want to combine it with `array_filter()` to remove empty items like so:

```
$test = array_filter(explode('/', $here));
```

For this, if you give it "/1/2/3//4/5/" you'll still only get [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to just make it `explode(trim($here,'/'))`?

Comment: @TimCompton That is definitely what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Because of the leading slash. This wouldn't.

```
$here = "1/2/3/4/ ";

$test = explode('/', $here);
var_export($test);
```

You also have an empty array element because of the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Because the delimiter is found at the start of the string.

Likewise if the delimiter is found at the end of the string then a empty string will be the last element of the array.

You can solve this by removing the delimiter string from the start and end of the string, eg. with trim:

```
$test = explode('/', trim($here, '/'));
```